# Solving $y^{(n)}(t)=f(t); t>0$ with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I will use the notation $\frac{d^n y}{dt^n} \equiv y^{(n)}$.

How do I solve this ODE?

$$y^{(n)}(t)=f(t); t>0;\\
y(0)=y_0, y'(0)=y_1, ..., y^{(n-1)}(0)=y_{n-1}$$

---

**What I did:**

The ODE is in the form $F(t,y^{(n)})=0$ so I should look for parametric solution
$\begin{cases}
t=\phi(\tau)\\
y^{(n)}=\psi(\tau)
\end{cases}$ so $y^{(n-1)}=\int\psi(\tau)\phi'(\tau)d\tau$ and the order is reduced by one.

In my problem, let's choose $\phi(\tau)=\tau; \psi_n=f(\tau)$ and $y^{(k-1)}=\psi_{k-1}(\tau)=\int \psi_k(\tau)d\tau$ where $k=1,2,...,n$

How do I apply the initial conditions here?

---

There is also an answer which reads

$$y(t)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^t (t-\tau)^{n-1}f(\tau)d\tau + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{y_i t^i}{i!}$$

How do I get this answer?

Comment: How about induction?

Comment: @BCLC Good point, but I still don't know how to apply initial conds for induction base case.

Comment: Initial condition in base case I think is y(0)=y0

Comment: @BCLC Indeed. And the general solution is $y=\int f(t)dt$. Why does it follow that $y=\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau + y_0$?

Comment: You'll get F(t) - F(0) + C. Note that F(0) is a constant so you'll end up getting the same thing as in the in the integral you presented...I think? Oh and F is any anti derivative of f hahaha